# Django debug toolbar template listing feature for Struts2

Tags: java, debugging, servlets, struts2, sitemesh

I'm developing a [Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/index.html) application that uses [Sitemesh](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/) as template engine. What I need is a list of all the templates (JSP) that are used by request.

In other projects I use [Django Framework](http://www.djangoproject.com/), with it I've this amazing [Debug Toolbar](http://robhudson.github.com/django-debug-toolbar/) that, besides many other useful info, provides me with the list of templates the request used for displaying the page.

[image: Django Debug Toolbar - Template Section]

This list is surprisingly helpful when in have more than 600 templates that forms a intricate template web and I need to change a `<br />` to a `<p></p>` in one of them.

Well I don't expect anything as nice as this for Struts2, just a raw list of `LOG.debug(<template>);` will make my work so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I read some [stuff](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/can-we-access-an-actions-result.html) and made the following class:

```
package x;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.entities.ResultConfig;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PreResultListener;

public class TemplatesDebugInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4030044344066761593L;
    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TemplatesDebugInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (ServletActionContext.getActionMapping() != null) {
                String className = invocation.getAction().getClass().getCanonicalName();
                String methodName = ServletActionContext.getActionMapping().getMethod();
                log.info("===========================");
                log.info(className+"."+methodName);
            }
            invocation.addPreResultListener(new PreResultListener() {
                public void beforeResult(ActionInvocation invocation,String resultCode) {
                    Map<String, ResultConfig> resultsMap = invocation.getProxy().getConfig().getResults();
                    ResultConfig finalResultConfig = resultsMap.get(resultCode);
                    log.info(finalResultConfig.getParams());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("[ERROR] Could not list templates: ", e);
        }
        return invocation.invoke();
    }
}
```

Added this to struts.xml:

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="templates" class="x.TemplatesDebugInterceptor" />
    (...)
    <interceptor-stack name="defaultStackBizgov">
        <interceptor-ref name="templates"/>
        (...)
```

And it's done!:

```
13:52:00,279 INFO  [STDOUT] [INFO] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-7) TemplatesDebugInterceptor - x.ProcedureDetailsAction.validateSubmitPublication
13:52:00,357 INFO  [STDOUT] [INFO] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-7) TemplatesDebugInterceptor - {location=/WEB-INF/jsp/indexPage.jsp}
13:52:00,763 INFO  [STDOUT] [INFO] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-7) TemplatesDebugInterceptor - {location=/WEB-INF/jsp/publicationView.jsp}
```

I will update this post if I find out some extra useful output.